# How to pass ThroughputMode for EFS in Cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-efs, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

Throughput mode can be provisioned or bursting. In case of provisioned, another property: "ProvisionedThroughPutInMibps" will need to be set.

Now if all these were to be passed as parameters to the template for the users to choose,
How to handle the validations for ThroughputMode?
i.e., User selects "bursting", now the parameter: "ProvisionedThroughPutInMibps" is of no use.(The AWS::NoValue can be used), but it's not allowed to go ahead without setting a value for "ProvisionedThroughPutInMibps"  (even if it's of no use)

Can "Rules" be of any use here?

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Parameters:
  ThroughputMode:
    Type: string
    AllowedValues:
      - bursting
      - provisioned
  ProvisionedThroughPutInMibps:
    Type: Number

Resources:
 
  FileSystemResource:
    Type: 'AWS::EFS::FileSystem'
    Properties:
      ThroughputMode: !Ref ThroughputMode
      ProvisionedThroughPutInMibps: !Ref ProvisionedThroughPutInMibps
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the actually template and show any errors or explain why its not working?

Comment: @Marcin , added sample in the question itself. Now, if I select ThroughputMode as provisioned and then proceed. The "ProvisionedThroughPutInMibps" should be a number error comes up. Now, I get that it's because I didn't enter a value over there... But, that value has no use!! (Since the throughput is bursting)

Comment: You can set default value of 0 to `ProvisionedThroughPutInMibps`, and then validate against this. The  "Rules" you mention could only be used when designing a template for Service Catalag. So you can use that if you want more control over input parameters.